# Passing argument to lua function after evaluating function in string

Tags: string, function, lua, arguments, lua-table

I have functions `process` and `matrix`. The following code works

```
process(matrix({{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}))
```

However the following doesn't work.

```
n='matrix({{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}})'
process(n)
```

It throws some error. The reason is obvious that process takes `n` as `string` rather than the output of the function `matrix`. So the basic difficulty involved here is about `evaluating` string from variable `n` and then give it as argument to the function `process`.  Here `loadstring` function is of no use as `matrix` is local function and can't be referred from `loadstring`.
Is there any work around for this? I hope that I have clearly stated the problem here. It is about evaluating (or unloading) string and then passing it as argument to another function. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as `matrix` is local function

Lua takes `local` declarations *seriously*. If a variable is declared `local`, it can only be accessed by code which is *statically* within the local scope of that variable. Strings which you later turn into code are not statically in the local scope and therefore cannot access `local` variables.

Now, with Lua 5.2+, you can provide `load` with a second parameter, a table which represents the global environment against which that Lua chunk will be built. If that table contains a `matrix` value, then the loaded string can access it. For Lua 5.1, you'd have to use `setfenv` on the function returned to `load` to accomplish a similar effect. The Lua 5.2+ method would look like this:

```
local env = {matrix = matrix}
local func = load("return matrix({{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}})", nil, "t", env)
process(func())
```

Note the following:

- You must create an explicit table which is the global environment. There's nothing you can pass that says "make my locals available"; you have to put every local you'd like to access there. Which is, generally speaking, why you pass these things as parameters or just make them globals.
- You explicitly need the `"return "` there if you want to get the results of the call to `matrix`.
- You have to call the function. Functions are values in Lua, so you can freely pass them around. But if you want to pass the *results* of a function to another function, you have to actually call it.

Comment: How to do it with setfenv? For the current answer, I don't get where to put string `n`.

Comment: @Maths89: I don't understand what you mean by "where to put string `n`". I copied your string exactly, with the necessary addition of `"return "`. That's where you put `n`.

Comment: local func = load("return''..n, nil, "t", env) doesn't work

Comment: @Maths89: I don't see the space at the end of `"return"`, the way it is in my example.

Comment: Yes It worked. Thanks for your great help. Could you signify the meaning of nil and "t" in load function?